# Doctrine 2 postPersist call does not work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need the Entity's ID and I am doing a PostPersist call. The following should work. I var_dump and I am indeed getting the ID and actually $this->path is correct when debugging. However, the result in the database is a null. As if the PostPersist never happened. What is wrong with this? Also, @HasLifecycleCallbacks is annotated at the top of my Entity class.

```
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
*/
public function setPathFromParent(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $e)
{
    $newTermData = $e->getEntity();
    $id = $newTermData->getId();

    if($this->getParentTermData() != '')
        $this->path = $this->getParentTermData()->getPath() . '.' . $this->getId();
    else
        $this->path = $id;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the ID? postPersist only happens after the database calls have been finished. I dont believe it will do another update

Comment: That would make sense. Well then, which lifecycle callback allows me to make this kind of change?

Comment: Honestly i wouldnt do it like that, just add that functionality to the getPath() call. so that php builds the path when its called.

Answer (score -1):

This is/was because in PostPersist the EntityManager will not flush any changes made to the entities.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist

If you want to avoid doing a followup update to the entity something like:

```
//Controller or other place to get 
$newTermData = //create it some how
$em->persist($newTermData);
$em->flush();
$id = $newTermData->getId();

if($newTermData->getParentTermData() != '')
    $newTermData->path = $newTermData->getParentTermData()->getPath() . '.' . $newTermData->getId();
else
    $newTermData->path = $id;

$em->flush($newTermData);
```

Then you could change from using an auto incremented ID column and then have doctrine handle that so its predictable what the next ID will be, then use `prePersist` to do what you want.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I want to be able to store a path field at the time of record creation.

Comment: You wont have access to the ID until after the record is created so if you dont want to generate the path then you will have to make an additional call in the controller.

Comment: @karmacode I realize this is SUPER late update, but after getting a downvote for the original answer i figured i would update the answer to a better solution.